# Can not start Hadoop Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, hadoop, vmware, virtual-machine, rhel

I recently downloaded a copy of the hadoop virtual image from http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html#vm

I am running my VMware Player on RHEL5 and as per the instructions, whenever I try and double click the .vmx file in the unzipped VM folder, the VMware Player loads but gives me an error saying "The Virtual Machine is busy". After clicking OK, the VM just sits there doing absolutely nothing. Where have I gone wrong here? Am I missing something? I checked my VM settings and everything looks fine (I have given it 512Mb of RAM, 25 GB harddisk and I know all this is more than sufficient)

I need to get this thing running for my project ASAP so please I need help. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this one out thanks to a page from a very well written blog.

Method 1: vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

Method 2:     a.) /etc/init.d/vmware stop
followed by   b.) rm -rf /var/run/vmware/*

Method 3: (This is what worked for me. Apparently sometimes there is an empty useless file created by the name of not-configured. Delete this. No Harm done :) )
rm -rf /etc/vmware/not_configured